# $q and resolving promises in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am not sure how to go about returning the promise. I have tried to return the result in a nested method but would prefer to return the result in two different methods as shown afterwards:

```
 $scope.relatedContacts = function (accountId) {
                if (!lodash.isNil(accountId)) {
                    try {
                        return restangular.one('user')
                       .one('contactimages')
                       .get({ 'mappedRelatedContactsPath': $scope.mappedRelatedContactsPath, "account": accountId })
                       .then(function (response) {
                             return response.data;});
                }
            }
```

Would prefer to fix the below example:

```
$scope.relatedContacts = function (accountId) {

                        if (!lodash.isNil(accountId)) {

                            try {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                    return restangular.one('user')
                                   .one('contactimages')
                                   .get({ 'mappedRelatedContactsPath': $scope.mappedRelatedContactsPath, "account": accountId })
                                    return deferred.promise;
                                }
                            catch (err) {
                                $scope.contactsPopulated = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

     $scope.relatedContacts().then(function (response) {
          //Some logic here          
    }
```

Currently I am getting : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
"

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember about consistency. The `isNil` if makes your function not returning anything in some cases (you will get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined "` error when `accountId` is not provided.

You have two ways to solve your problem.

**First way:**

```
$scope.relatedContacts = function (accountId) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (!lodash.isNil(accountId)) {
      try {
        return restangular.one('user')
          .one('contactimages')
          .get({ 'mappedRelatedContactsPath': $scope.mappedRelatedContactsPath, "account": accountId })
          .then(function(response) {
            resolve(response.data)
          }, reject);
      }
      catch (err) {
        $scope.contactsPopulated = false;
        reject(err);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

**The second way (using defer).**

```
$scope.relatedContacts = function (accountId) {
  var def = $q.defer();
  if (!lodash.isNil(accountId)) {
    try {
      restangular.one('user')
        .one('contactimages')
        .get({ 'mappedRelatedContactsPath': $scope.mappedRelatedContactsPath, "account": accountId })
        .then(function(response) {
          def.resolve(response.data)
        }, def.reject);
    }
    catch (err) {
      $scope.contactsPopulated = false;
      def.reject(err);
    }
  }
  return def;
};
```

You should check official reference about `$q` service:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

There are numerous examples of typical promise usages.

Comment: for the first method I added $q in my controller but getting error now :TypeError: $q is not a function :  .controller('SelectUserController', ['$scope', 'PubSub', 'Pnotify', 'Common.InfiniteListService', 'SelectUserService', 'Restangular','$q',
            function ($scope, pubSub, pnotify, InfiniteListService, selectUserService, restangular, $q) {

Comment: The issue is I want to carry out some logic with the response: eg; when the promise is reolved, I want to check for additional logic.

Comment: The isNil will work because I am calling the method only if account is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to return the value and add additional method to deal with the response.

```
 $scope.relatedContacts = function (accountId) {

                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        if (!lodash.isNil(accountId)) {

                            try {

                                deferred.resolve(restangular.one('user')
                                   .one('contactimages')
                                   .get({ 'mappedRelatedContactsPath': $scope.mappedRelatedContactsPath, "account": accountId }));

                            }
                            catch (err) {
                                $scope.contactsPopulated = false;
                                deferred.reject(err);
                            }
                        }
                        deferred.promise.then(function (response) {
                            var tests = response;
                            return $q.when();
                        },
                       function () {
                           console.log("1st reject");
                           return $q.reject();
                       });
                        return deferred.promise;

                    };
```